# turn off push notification by a switcher swift 3

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3, push-notification

```
@IBAction func touched(_ sender: PWSwitch) {

    pwSwitch.setOn(true, animated: true)
    if pwSwitch.on {

        if cover.isHidden == true {
            cover.isHidden = false
            lable.text = "off "
           // stop all the activities 

        } else {

            if cover.isHidden == false  {
                cover.isHidden = true
                lable.text = " "
           // reload all the activities 


            }
        }



       }
}
```

I have this button where by the switcher I cover the view controller by UIView or display it. I'm trying to find a way when the view controller is covered I wish to stop push notification and HTTP request.

in this view controller I have a function that calls my API every 1 minute and I want to stop that with the push notification.

Is there any way to do this ?